# Rewrite url does not work with multi paramater

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am quite new to rewriterule and i m trying to rewrite as below

```
index.php?controller=Listings&action=newview&id=3
```

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/?(.*)$ /index.php?controller=Listings&action=news&$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

and when i call "/newview/id/3" at url and it didn't work thank you advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your rule says: `^/?news/?`, yet, you are going to the URL `/newview/`. Obviously this isn't going to work, since "newview" is definitely not "news".

Secondly, your grouping., `(.*)`, matches `id/3` and you are backreferences it. Obviously, `id/3` isn't `id=3`. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?newview/id/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?controller=Listings&action=news&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```